# How to extract common elements of values (which are lists) of dictionary and map them back to their keys as their new values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

`dict = {'A':[1,2,5],'B':[3,6,13],'C':[2,3,6],'D':[4,6,8]}`

I want to extract all the common elements into a new dictionary as keys with their corresponding values as the keys in `dict` which they are extracted from.
What I want is:

`newdict = {1:['A'],2:['A','C'],3:['B','C'],4:['D'],5:['A'],6:['B','C','D'],8:['D'],13:['B']}` .

I have tried to compare values of each element by copying the dictionary `dict` and comparing each of the elements (`dict1` is copy of `dict`):

```
for i, j in zip(range(len(dict)), range(len(dict1))):
    for m, n in zip(range(len(dict[i])), range(len(dict1[j]))):
        if dict[i][m] == dict1[j][n]:
            print(dict[i][m])
            
for i in range(len(dict)):
    for k in range(len(dict[i])):
        #print(dict[i][k])
        for j in range(dict[i+1][k], len(g)):
            #print(j)
            if dict[i][k] == dict[i+1][j]:
                print(dict[i][k])
```

However, I ended up with index out of range error or unable to get the proper keys even before being able to extract the common repeating values. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (to reduce bloat code)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d2 = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in d.items():
  for number in v:
    d2[number].append(k)
```

---

```
>>> print(d2)
defaultdict(list,
            {1: ['A'],
             2: ['A', 'C'],
             3: ['B', 'C'],
             4: ['D'],
             5: ['A'],
             6: ['B', 'C', 'D'],
             8: ['D'],
             13: ['B']})
```

You can also use a normal dictionary, there's just some more checks to add:

```
d2 = {}

for k,v in d.items():
  for number in v:
    if number in d2:
      d2[number].append(k)
    else:
      d2[number] = [k]
```

Finally, avoid naming your dictionary `dict`, since it overwrites the built-in `dict` name.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in case the the value for a key repeats as ['A','A'], how to remove the repititions of 'A' ?

Comment: You can use a `set` intead of a `list` in the default dict. And have `d2[number] = {k}` and `d2[number].add(k)` in the second method.

Comment: The second method converts all the values to dictionaries instead of lists. Any way to get back lists format?

Comment: @PriyankushGhosh they are not dictionaries. They are sets. You can always do, as a final step, `d2 = {k:list(v) for k,v in d2.items()}` to make the sets be lists again.